# Pine Script (TradingView) get next session details

Tags: pine-script

Using Pine Script I could draw a custom line with below code.

```
l = line.new(timestamp(2020, 04, 07, 09, 15), 17500, timestamp(2020, 04, 08, 09, 15), 17500, xloc.bar_time)
line.delete(l[1])
```

I would like to draw a custom line for **next trading day** (something like below image).

Is there a way to find upcoming trading day's timestamp in Pine Script ??

[image]

Comment: @PineCoders-LucF : Could you please help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work on 24/7 markets. You'll probably need to make adjustments when you can test on a live market:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
y  = high
x1 = timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow) + 1, 9, 30)
x2 = timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow) + 2, 9, 30)
var line l = na
if barstate.islast
    if na(l)
        // Only create line once, then update it.
        l := line.new(x1, y, x2, y, xloc.bar_time)
        // Make 2 if blocks same type so compiler doesn't complain.
        int(na)
    else
        line.set_xy1(l, x1, y)
        line.set_xy2(l, x2, y)
        int(na)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I created a script here https://in.tradingview.com/script/x82KBd8H-Today-Tomorrow-s-CPR/  Please review and let me know if i can improve it in any ways

Comment: Is there a way to identify holidays & weekends in TradingView / Pine Script ?

Comment: How you did it there in the update looks fine. Congrats on script. Be careful with your `lookahead` though. Should use ON when referring to past values (`high[1]`) of series as you do, but OFF when using the series' current value (`high`), otherwise you're introducing lookahead bias.

Comment: Thanks for your review & suggestion.